# Authentication with JWT: Securing Views from the consuming client perspective

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

I have created a Web API using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and it uses (successfully) JWT as a method of authorising requests.

The API is linked to a SQL Server database. 
My users are stored in it using `Identity` as the base framework.

To authorise access for my API I take the username and password which is checked against the stored (`Identity` based) user.

Successful login returns an `Access Token` (with a 30min life).

Upon first logging in, a `Refresh Token` is generated and stored against the Identity user and sent back from the API.

All of this works well. My next step was to create a separate .NET Core 2.1 MVC site which consumes the API.

My question is:

> From the MVC site point of view, how do I secure my controllers and views based on this security set up? I would normally use the `[Authorize]` attribute as part of Identity.

All I have on the MVC site side at the moment is the `Access Token` (and `Refresh token`) for the user in question.

**I'm thinking the following solution:**

- MVC Site has it's own database and authentication for users (using `Identity`).
- The connection (credentials/tokens) to the API is stored separately in the MVC site database and used as a 'global' way on the server-side to execute calls against the API

Comment: What specifically are you asking? "How do I secure my MVC Website?" .. If thats the question, you've already answered it - in the question.

Comment: I guess I want to know if I’m on the right tracks given the separation of my “authorised content” via the api. But yea, I was wondering if I had already answered the question

Comment: Clarification: Are you looking for a way to "lock down" your WebAPI? I'm asking because if so, you can probably simplify it all. MVC does the authentication, and is the only application authorized to call the API (via something like JWT). So effectively, the API app cedes access restrictions to MVC app.

Comment: I think a central identity provider like Identity Server would help you. Identity Server can be configured to use identity, so your existing users would be there. Then, protecting the MVC app is easy, just using the authorization_code flow. Your API is registered in the IdentityServer and the MVC app can request tokens to be able to call it. This is the client_credentials flow.

Comment: Usually, I'd say APIs are protected by JWT tokens, not by authentication users itself. It should trust some identity system that are part of the "network". I think you should shift the authentication to either something like Identity Server, or in the MVC app itself.

Comment: @jpgrassi Ok got any good tutorials ? I have a feeling something “in the middle” is missing here. I want to make this a nice solid system

Comment: If it helps, I’m working with azure.

Comment: Sure. Have you heard about Identity Server before? Are you familiar with OAuth 2/OpenId connect? If not, I'd suggest reading a bit about it first, (but don't get overwhelmed..). About samples: Identity Server repo on github has tons of samples. This particular one might fit your needs: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts/8_AspNetIdentity  It demonstrates having a central identity provider, and several clients consuming it. Api, MVC, javascript and so on.

Comment: @jpgrassi thanks for that - i'll have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

You should use an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework. please check  [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It also support asp.net core identity

> IdentityServer is an OpenID Connect provider - it implements the
>   OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 protocols.
>
> Different literature uses different terms for the same role - you
>   probably also find security token service, identity provider,
>   authorization server, IP-STS and more.
>
> But they are in a nutshell all the same: a piece of software that
>   issues security tokens to clients.
>
> IdentityServer has a number of jobs and features - including:
>
> - protect your resources
> - authenticate users using a local account store or via an external    identity provider
> - provide session management and single sign-on
> - manage and authenticate clients
> - issue identity and access tokens to clients
> - validate tokens

Comment: Thanks for your response - I'll check that out.